# Positioning DIVs with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs inside each other. The inner DIV contains an image. I'm trying to add a floating text over that image in the top right corner. I can't figure out how to make that text to use inner DIV's positions instead of the outer one.

Here is what I got so far

CSS:

```
html {
    background: #EEF0F3;
}
.outer {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:20px 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 680px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0px; 
   right: 0px; 
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;
   background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
   padding: 0px 10px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2><span>Title 1</span></h2>
        <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code in JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UM8ea/

If I set positioning to:

```
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 20px; 
   right: -20px; 
}
```

I get the desired result, but that feels like workaround rather than a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this behaviour because `.outer` is wider than the image, and then, `.inner` too. The `h2` is positioned related to `.inner`, and go to right.

If you set `.outer` to have 640px width (as the image) you get the [desired result](http://jsfiddle.net/UM8ea/3/).

[Other solution](http://jsfiddle.net/UM8ea/4/) is to set `margin: 0 20px;` on `.inner`

If you want the [text positioned all top](http://jsfiddle.net/UM8ea/5/) the image you can set `h2 {margin:0;}` in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTwbn/1/)

```
.outer {
background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
margin: 0 auto;
padding:20px 0px;
position: relative;
width: 680px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**for h2**

```
 h2 
{ 
position: absolute; 
top: 5px; 
right: 20px; 
margin:0;
}
```